# Which systems use the Cthulhu Mythos?

Tags: cthulhu-mythos, game-recommendation

I need to know which systems use the Cthulhu Mythos. Could you give me a list?

Please give only systems that specifically reference the Cthulhu Mythos. For example, don't bother listing *Escape From Tentacle City*: tentacles don't make it Mythos. Similarly, don't give me minor references: don't list, say, *Paranoia*, just because a Paranoia scenario once mentioned Cthulhu.

Also, don't list all the different Call of Cthulhu settings: don't, for example, list Cthulhu Invictus.

Everything else - CthulhuTech, UnSpeakable, Trail of Cthulhu -  is fair game. I'm particularly interested in little systems I haven't heard about.

(And this is Community Wiki, of course.)

Answer (score 8):

In the [1980 edition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deities_%26_Demigods#1st_Edition_Advanced_Dungeons_.26_Dragons) of **Deities and Demigods**, *Advanced Dungeons & Dragons* compiled a set of statistics for the Old Ones of Lovecraft's Mythos, including Cthulhu. This material was later removed at the request of Chaosium Publishing, who had already acquired the RPG rights from Arkham House.

Comment: Interesting, but could we stick to systems only, please? If we widen it to Cthulhu references, there'll be too much stuff.

Comment: My thought was that this was an example of system: that is, the D&D mechanics used to stat up Lovecraftian horrors, as opposed to "Cthulhu shows up in *Ghostbusters*, so he's suitable for the RPG version." Is there a border you're drawing?

Comment: The border I'm trying to draw is: if the system doesn't focus on the Mythos, it's out. D&D doesn't focus on the Mythos. (Of course, this gets harder with thing like GURPS.)

Comment: The Cthulhu Mythos was actually pretty significant to D&D then. It's only not obvious now because the official use of Mythos stuff was *verboten* for so long. The inclusion of the Far Realms in 4e is a hat-tip to this aspect of old-school D&D.

Answer (score 8):

Wildfire's **[Cthulhutech](http://www.cthulhutech.com/)** using a proprietary engine. Formerly released through Mongoose Publications.

Wildfire's **[Cthonian Stars](http://chthonianstars.com/)**, released through Mongoose.

9th Level Games' **[Cthulhu for President](http://rpggeek.com/rpgitem/63511/cthulhu-for-president)** is a tongue in cheek game using their BEER Engine (used also for *Kobolds Ate My Baby* 3E & SDE and *Ninja Burger* 1E).

Ken Hite and Robin Laws' **[Trail of Cthulhu](http://www.pelgranepress.com/site/?page_id=242)** which is a standalone version of Gumshoe.

**[Cthulhu Dice: The RPG](http://rpggeek.com/rpgitem/80231/cthulhu-dice-the-rpg)** is someone's homebrew using Steve Jackson Games' [Cthulhu Dice](http://www.sjgames.com/dice/cthulhudice/) for task resolution.

Answer (score 7):

Unless I'm mistaken all over the place, *[Nemesis](http://www.nemesis-system.com/)* is pretty well front-loaded for Cthulhoid shenanigans.

Comment: Nemesis is pretty cool. My only major concern about it is the way the skill curves work as you add more dice - there's not much graduation in the "normal" human range, IMO. But the UA Madness Meters have a lot going for them.

Answer (score 6):

The best known of them all is of course [Call of Cthulhu](http://www.chaosium.com/), which has been around since 1981, and is based on Chaosium's Basic Role-Playing system.

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to be cheeky and list [Cthulhu Dark](http://www.thievesoftime.com/news/?p=41), just in case you've somehow forgotten about it!  ;-)

Also [Unspeakable](http://www.memento-mori.com/inspectres/unspeakable.pdf), a supplemental ruleset for Inspectres.

And [Chthonian](http://www.harlekin-maus.com/games/chthonian/chthonian.html), although this has been "currently being rewritten" for some time.

Answer (score 4):

### Delta Green

One notable offshoot of the *Call of Cthulhu* RPG was the *Delta Green* setting (1997), which merged the Cthulhu Mythos with the pre-millennial conspiracy genre popular at the time.

Answer (score 4):

[The Laundry](http://www.leisuregames.com/cgi-bin/sh000001.pl?REFPAGE=http://www.leisuregames.com/&WD=laundry&PN=the_laundry_rpg_complimentary_pdf.html#a35181#a35181) (2010, ISBN 1-907204-93-8, Gareth Hanrahan, published by [Cubicle 7](http://www.cubicle7.co.uk/our-games/) is set in the Charles Stross's "Bob Howard — Laundry" series of books.  It uses CoC rules, if you are bothered by those.  Note that two novellas are available for free [Down On The Farm](http://www.tor.com/stories/2008/07/down-on-the-farm) and [Overtime](http://www.tor.com/stories/2009/12/overtime) if you wanted to check the background material.  There is an adventure module [Black Back Jobs](http://www.leisuregames.com/cgi-bin/sh000001.pl?REFPAGE=http://www.leisuregames.com/&WD=laundry&PN=the_laundry_black_bag_jobs_complimentary_pdf.html#a11000#a11000) as well.

Answer (score 3):

[GURPS Cthulhu Punk](http://www.sjgames.com/gurps/books/CthulhuPunk/), and the [D20 version of Call of Cthulhu](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0786926392), are two other systems using the Cthulhu Mythos.

Answer (score 1):

It pains me to even mention this game, given that most reviewers have described it as adolescent at best and infantile at worst (I cannot claim to have read it, nor am I likely to).

However, it would appear that [Empire of Satanis](http://www.rpg.net/reviews/archive/12/12636.phtml) (and I'm linking to one of those reviews here so that people get the picture) would appear to qualify under the conditions that you have given. That is, it is an RPG (even a playable one, apparently) and the author believes it to be Lovecraftian, even though many Lovecraft fans would vehemently disagree. It's the Cthulhu Mythos, Jim, but definitely not as we know it.

I am off to stick pins in my eyes by way of light relief.

Answer (score 1):

[Realms of Cthulhu](http://realityblurs.com/wordpress/?page_id=911) is a highly flexible system designed to allow you to play a range of games in the Lovecraftian mythos - from CoC investigation to high-tech monster-hunters etc. The underlying crunch is Savage Worlds.