# What RPG systems are Designed for a "Traditional" Call of Cthulhu Scenario

Tags: game-recommendation, call-of-cthulhu, trail-of-cthulhu, call-of-cthulhu-d20

What RPG systems are there for a traditional Call of Cthulhu adventure (e.g. a basic premise of being investigators in 20th century/modern timeframe within the Lovecraft Mythos)? I know that there is the Chaosium Call of Cthulhu system, which I understand is the grandaddy of them all, and I have heard that a d20 version was made. Which others are there? Also, are they in print?

Also, could I have a bit of information about what the basic differences are (e.g. main mechanic, how it tries to capture the feel of the setting) to better help me decide which one I'd like to use?

I also realize that there are a bunch of other spinoff games based on the Cthulhu mythos (e.g. *The Laundry* and *CthulhuTech*) but I'm not interested in those at the moment. Also, I'm not looking for general horror RPGs, but rather ones that are specifically designed to be set in the Cthulhu Mythos.

Comment: I'm torn on whether to close this as a duplicate of http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5025/which-systems-use-the-cthulhu-mythos, a bad old list style question itself, or because it's too vague of a question.  What is the real problem you're trying to solve?  This sounds like a system-recommendation question which should adhere to RPG.SE's system-rec guidelines on our [Meta](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/a/1071/760).  In fact, I'm going to close this while clarification happens so we don't pull bad answers in the meantime.

Comment: I'm wondering, too, whether you've conflated *Call of Cthulhu*, the RPG, with the broader Cthulhu Mythos. Are you looking for all games that use the Lovecraftian Mythos, or specifically for variations on the CoC RPG?

Comment: My question as originally posted does have a lot in common with the question mxyzplk posted, which I didn't find because it was labeled with the `cthulhu` tag rather than `call-of-cthulhu`. I've revised my question to differentiate from that question by asking for systems that are for a "traditional" game used in the Chaosium system.

Comment: OK, so now this isn't a duplicate.  Is it, however, a "practical, answerable question based on actual problems that you face"? I know we have a contest on but I don't want to see a lot of seeded questions garnering trivia for its own sake.  Why do you need this, what end is it serving?

Comment: I would like to know what systems are available to help me decide what I might use for a Call of Cthulhu game, which I guess I didn't post originally (the other question did help, but I realized I wanted a more specific answer after I thought about the game I wanted to run). Even if I wasn't planning on running a game, wouldn't wanting to know for my own edification be enough? That seems to be most of the questions about system differences or history of gaming.

Comment: This does seem like a request for a list of Cthulhu-related RPGs, without any actual recommendations. It seems like you're asking for some Googling, rather than specific recommendations based on actual experience.

Comment: There seems to be a demand for an answer to this question, given that there are several upvotes. I feel that this meets the guidelines for system recommendation questions, but if others disagree, then it could be closed.

Comment: I'm still not entirely clear on what you want. Do you want systems that are built for generic horror games, that could be used to play a Cthulhu game? Systems that are specifically built around the Cthulhu Mythos? Systems that are horror games in the style of the Mythos (Dark Conspiracy)? Systems that include the Mythos, but aren't really used for Mythos-style stories (Pathfinder)? Perhaps being more specific might help.

Comment: I've clarified what I want in the question, indicating I'm wanting the second option from your list of choices.

Comment: Your refinement of the question makes it more of a list than when it started.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- *Call of Cthulhu* is being given its [first real overhaul in decades](http://forum.rpg.net/showthread.php?670344-Call-of-Cthulhu-7th-edition-is-coming!). The system is d100, and the emphasis is on immersion in the game world. The default setting is the 1920s, but there are expansion materials available for other eras. Chaosium has created an extensive body of well-regarded CoC adventures over many years. Here's co-creator [Sandy Peterson talking about the game](http://rpggeek.com/thread/687972/here-i-am-reviewing-my-own-game).
- *Trail of Cthulhu* is built on the GUMSHOE system, and it emphasizes the investigative aspects of a Cthulhu campaign. Primary and secondary clues give a richness to discovery. The default setting is the 1930s. Because it's a much newer game, ToC doesn't have a vast library of published adventures. Here's a [favorable review from RPGGeek](http://rpggeek.com/thread/682023/a-perfect-marriage-of-setting-rules).
- *Realms of Cthulhu* hews to the Savage Worlds "Fast! Furious! Fun!" mantra. It takes more of a pulp approach than either CoC or ToC, but it also provides some modifications to the core Savage Worlds rules in order to more closely fit the genre. As with ToC, there is no big bunch of published adventures. However, guidelines for converting CoC adventures are included in the book. Here's a [favorable review from Gnome Stew](http://www.gnomestew.com/reviews/review-realms-of-cthulhu/). Amazon lists eight copies available.
- *Cthulhu Dark* is Graham Walmsley's rules-light (the free PDF is 4 pages long) system. Here's a [review](http://thee-rapture.carnel.org/reviews/cthulhu-dark) and here's [the game](http://catchyourhare.com/files/Cthulhu%20Dark.pdf).
- *d20 Call of Cthulhu* has been out of print for some time, as the license between WotC and Chaosium expired. It can be found used. Some people, like this reviewer, [found it better than the original](http://www.rpg.net/reviews/archive/12/12250.phtml).

Answer (score 5):

1. There is a True20 treatment of the Mythos entitled [Shadows of Cthulhu](http://www.rpgobjects.com/index.php?c=product&o%5Bp_id%5D=384)
2. Dennis Detwiller adapted the One-Roll Engine to the Mythos in [Nemesis](http://www.arcdream.com/pdf/Nemesis.pdf)
3. Delta Green will have its own system at some point, as well.